# In a Java 7 multicatch block what is the type of the caught exception?

Tags: java, exception, java-7

In a Java 7 multicatch block such as the following:

```
try {
    // code that throws exception
} catch (CharacterCodingException | UnknownServiceException ex) {
    // handle exception
}
```

what is the compile-time type of `ex`? Is it the most derived class that both exception types have in common? In this example that would be an `IOException`.

Comment: it would make sense to be whichever is thrown, but you can easily check by printing out `ex.getClass()`

Comment: If you need to have different behavior based on what the caught exception is, then you shouldn't be using a multicatch block - break it out into multiple catch blocks.

Comment: @Jon: "Type" is a compile-time concept, you're talking about the runtime class of the object.

Comment: @Jon: I'd like to know the compile time type of `ex`, not the type at run time.

Comment: @Shakedown I don't want different behaviour; I'd just like to know the type of the exception.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, the type of `ex` is the most specific supertype of both `CharacterCodingException` and `UnknownServiceException`, which would be `IOException`.

**Edit:** Straight from the horse's mouth on http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~darcy/ProjectCoin/ProjectCoin-Documentation-v0.83.html#multi_catch:

> Informally, the lub (least upper bound) is the most specific supertype of the types in question.

Comment: Do you have any references? The [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) seems rather light.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted answer it is.

Comment: For future reference: `lub` computation definition is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7

Answer (score 14):

In JSL 7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20-510

§14.20 > The declared type of an exception parameter that denotes its type as a union with
alternatives D1 | D2 | ... | Dn is lub(D1, D2, ..., Dn) (§15.12.2.7).

The definition of `lub()` i.e. *the least upper bound* is quite convoluted. Fortunately types we are talking about here are usually simply non generic subclasses of Throwable, and `lub()` yields the most specific super class.

For a more complicated case, consider

```
class E1 extends Exception implements G<A>
class E2 extends Error implements G<B>

lub(E1, E2) = Throwable & G<?>
```